# Чтение видео в C# как последовательность байтов ,обработка их как 32 битных чисел(BigEndian) и запись в массив

Tags: c#, winforms, видео, byte

Доброго времени суток.Подскажите как решить подобную задачу?Методы вроде бы нарыл,но есть куча нюансов,и хотелось бы услышать советы или примеры.Работаю с формами.
В дальнейшем полученные числа будут обрабатываться двумя алгоритмами сортировок.(с этим помогать не надо)
А вот как правильно прочесть видео?
Нужно ли создавать массив байтов по 4 для конвертации в 32 битные числа?(записали 4 байта -> записали число в ячейку массива)
Или этот класс сам разделит байты?

Comment: А причём тут WinForms?

Comment: Думал в работе с формами будут какие то свои особенности,но все оказалось просто и понятно.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Собственно, в чём вопрос?

Открываем поток и читаем с помощью [`BinaryReader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.binaryreader(v=vs.110).aspx). Нужны 32-битные числа - используем метод `ReadInt32`.

Для конвертации из BigEndian можно использовать [`IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x1886wea.aspx).

```
using (var stream = new FileStream(filename, FileMode.Open))
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
    while (reader.PeekChar() != -1)
    {
        int bigEndian = reader.ReadInt32();
        int littleEndian = IPAddress.NetworkToHostOrder(bigEndian);
        // Используем полученное число ...
    }
}
```

Примечание: размер файла должен быть кратным 4.

Comment: как оказалось,лучше (в моем случае) привести вторую строку ,к такому виду:
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream, Encoding.ASCII))

Comment: @VladFinni - если читаются только числа, то кодировка не имеет никакого значения. Она учитывается только при чтении строк и символов.

Comment: как оказалось - имеет. Почему то буфер маленький был с другой кодировкой и дальше 13 элемента в массиве - считывать не хотело.